# Как переставить строки массива местами7

Tags: c

Дана матрица целых чисел, нужно упорядочить ее строки по возрастанию значений их наибольших элементов

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#define N 1000
#define F 1000

void func(int a[][N], int m, int n) {
    int max = a[0][0];
    int i_max = 0;
    int j_max = 0;
    printf("Исходная матрица:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=%d ", i + 1, j + 1, a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nГотовая матрица:\n"); //матрица с переставленными строками
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=%d ", i + 1, j + 1, a[i][j]);
            if (a[i][j] > max) {
                max = a[i][j];
                i_max = i;
                j_max = j;
            }
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int a[F][N];
    int m, n;
    printf("Размерность матрицы: ");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &m, &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("матрица[%d][%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    func(a, m, n);
}
```

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать динамические массивы? Все же 4 Мб один массив в стеке — мне кажется многовато...

Comment: сделайте массив указателей на строки в динамической памяти, и сортируйте этот массив указателей.

Answer (score 0):

Большие источники данных не помещают в область данных для временных объектов. А ваша переменная `int a[F][N];` будет находиться именно там и вполне программа будет падать из-за недостаточного места памяти в стеке.
Чтобы быстро перемещать строки матрицы нужно поменять её тип на массив указателей на строки массива. А чтобы хватало памяти, эти строки нужно получить из свободной памяти с помощью `malloc`.

Пример :

```
// массив указателей на строки
int * a [ F ] ;
// выделяем память для строк
for ( int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++ i )
  a [ i ] = malloc ( sizeof ( int [ n ] ) ) ;
// наибольший элемент каждой строки матрицы храним отдельно
int ma [ F ] ;
// ищем для каждой строки максимум
// j - индекс строки 
ma [ j ] = a [ j ] [ 0 ] ;
for ( int i = 1 ; i < n ; ++ i )
  if ( ma [ j ] < a [ j ] [ i ] )
    ma [ j ] = a [ j ] [ i ] ;
// дальше можно сортировать массив ma и одновременно со строками матрицы
// простая квадратичная сортировка i < j
if ( ma [ i ] > ma [ j ] ) {
  int tmp = ma [ i ] ;
  ma [ i ] = ma [ j ] ;
  ma [ j ] = tmp ;
  int * tmpl = a [ i ] ;
  a [ i ] = a [ j ] ;
  a [ j ] = tmpl ;
}
// освобождаем память
for ( int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++ i )
  free ( a [ i ] ) ;
```